# Set cookie to redirect user if set cookie exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have some experience with JavaScript, but I'm racking my brain with cookies. I'm trying to set a cookie for users who access page X, and then redirect them to that same page X if they visit page Y.

See a more detailed example:

When a user visits `https://www.example.com/page.html`, I need a cookie to be set.

When this same user visits `https://www.example.com/redirect.html`, I need to check if the cookie that was set on `https://www.example.com/page.html` exists, if it exists then this user must be redirect to `https://www.example.com/page.html`.

Basically it's setting a cookie, if that cookie exists then something happens. I know how to do the redirect with JavaScript, but how do I set and read this cookie?

Comment: what framework are you using? start by looking at this page
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can create routes and set and receive cookies in the request and response object.

Set a cookie like this:  res.cookie(`cookie_name,`cookie value);

Read a cookie like this:  req.cookie['cookie_name'];

[More about using cookies here](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/what-are-cookies-nodejs/)

Comment: I created a cookie with `document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2031 23:59:59 UTC; path=/"` and then read it with `if(document.cookie.indexOf("username") > -1 ){`. Worked well, but is it correct? I'm not using node.js

Comment: take a look at the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie